# Bluemix cloud foundry logs

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm unable to look at application logs:

1. cf logs output is empty
2. kibana doesn't show all logs (i don't know)
3. the log file created by my app has not been updated

The application is runnig, why the log doesn't work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `cf logs AppName` is a tail so only shows what happens *after* you start the command.  You need `cf logs AppName --recent` to get the full log.  But this can be empty if it hasn't been written to recently. Per bluemix docs:

> Bluemix keeps a limited amount of log information.

I could never figure out what exactly 'limited' means.   For me it generally has about a day.  If you need longer you have to stream it to another logging system like Anatoly suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your application putting logs per https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/monitor_log/logging/cfapps/logging_writing_to_log_from_cf_app.html#logging_writing_to_log_from_cf_app and do not see the logs via cf logs APPNAME --recent

Outside of CLI and Kibana you can verify the logging functionality with external logging provider (like https://papertrailapp.com/) per https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/monitor_log/logging/external/logging_external_hosts.html#thirdparty_logging